# No keyboard entries possible in gitpod.io terminal

Tags: android, gitpod

I want to use gitpod.io as IDE. This works great with Firefox on Linux. But on my Android Tablet (Android 4.2.2) I am not able to write in the terminal window (tried Firefox and Chrome). Only the Enter-key is accepted. Writing into files is no problem.

Has anyone an idea what may lock the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in [Theia IDE](https://www.theia-ide.org/) or Gitpod.

Gitpod has a [public bug tracker](https://github.com/gitpod-io/gitpod/issues/). I have [reported it there](https://github.com/gitpod-io/gitpod/issues/480).